# How can i configure mailhog in my laravel application

Tags: laravel, mailhog

I have a .env file looks like this:

```
MAIL_MAILER='mailgun'
MAIL_HOST='smtp.mailgun.org'
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION='SSL'
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

but i get this error when i want to send e-mails.

`Connection could not be established with host "mailpit:1025": stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mailpit failed:`

what can i do to solve this problem?

I already change .env file but still got the same error.

Comment: you need to set your host to `localhost` if you are not using docke/laravel sail. if you are using docker/laravel sail you need to set your host to `mailhog`

Answer (score 1):

If you have windows system and you are not using laravel sail, then your mail config of .env file should look like this.

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="admin@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

open localhost:8025 on browser after running mailhog.exe as an admin.

you can install the same from below link

https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog/releases

Answer (score 0):

If you're using docker, let's ensure the mailhog container and laravel container are in same network bridge. Hope this helps.